# Add options from controller to view.. CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to add an option from the controller to the view directly .. the moment I get the array data from there with the following code:

```
public function select_dependent() {
    $aData = array(); //Variable para pasar a la vista 
    $data = $this->input->post('id');
    $tipus = $this->input->post('tipus');

    if($tipus == "modelo") {
        $aData['aModels'] = $this->pedidos_model->get_modelos($data);
    }
}
```

In the view, i have the following code:

```
<select name="modelo" class="span8" id="modelo">
<?if(isset($aModels)):?>
    <?foreach($aModels as $row):?>
    <option value="<?=$row['IDPRODUCTOS']?>"><?=$row['NOMBRE']?></option>
    <?endforeach;?>
<?endif;?>
</select>
```

And in the model I have this:

```
public function get_modelos($valor) {
    $oQuery = $this->db->query("dbo.CO_GETPRODUCTO @IDTIPOS ='".$valor."'");

    $aResult = $oQuery->result_array();
    return $aResult;
}
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Form Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) to generate the `select/dropdown` element easily:

```
// In your controller method
$this->load->helper('form');
// ...
if($tipus == "modelo") {
    $aData['aModels'] = $this->pedidos_model->get_modelos($data);
    $aData['selected'] = 'use_a_value_to_be_selected';
    // Load the view and pass the $aData
    $this->load->view('blogview', $aData);
}

// In your view
echo form_dropdown('modelo', $aModels, $selected, 'class="span8" id="modelo"');
```

Your question is not so clear about the problem so can't be more specific but you got the idea.